# Why reset the customer session data when FPC is enabled?

Tags: magento2, customer, session

Regarding this [article](https://ranasohel.me/2017/05/05/how-to-get-customer-id-from-block-when-full-page-cache-enable-in-magento-2/) from @SohelRana what is the business or technical decision to empty the customer session data when FPC is enable?